# Geometric demonstration involving ex-circles and in-circles of $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry

Let there be a triangle $\triangle ABC$ with incenter $I$. Incircle touches $\overline{BC}$ at $D$. Then a perpendicular is drawn to $\overline{BC}$ at $D$, which cuts the in circle at $E$. $\overline{AE}$ extended intersects $\overline{BC}$ at $F$.

> *Prove that the ex-circle of triangle $\triangle ABC$, touching $\overline{BC}$ passes through $F$.*

[image]

Please I need help to solve this. Also I'd like to have the properties of in-circle, ex-circle, orthocentre cleared (explained).

Comment: You can consider $\Delta ABC$ as a triangle in $\mathbb{R^2}$ with the property O is mid point of $BC$ and Prove $AB+BF$ is semi perimeter of $\Delta ABC$.

Comment: @RSalimi can u explain

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's draw the line $\alpha$ perpendicular to $DE$, passing through $E$
Suppose that $\alpha$ cut $AB$, $AC$ at $X$, $Y$

$(I)$ is the ex-circle of $\triangle AXY$, where $E$ is the tangency point
$A$ is the similarity center of $\triangle AXY$ and $\triangle ABC$
Homothety(center=$A$) send $E$ to the tangency point of $\triangle ABC$ and its excircle

Comment: Prove that the ex-circle of triangle △ABC, touching BC passes through F.

Comment: The proof   is already done.

Comment: where is it done?

Comment: in last sentence